# Internet Archive Book Reader - how to set default display mode to 1up (single page)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the Internet Archive Book Reader plugin for a website I'm working on. The images I want to display are long, thin horizontal pages, so Book Reader's 2up (two pages shown at a time) method doesn't work for this (it just looks really strange).

How do I set the default mode for Book Reader to be 1up (one page at a time)? Yes, the user can select it on the bottom navbar but that's not professional.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the book reader like this:

```
instantiateBookReader('#BookReader', {
  defaults: 'mode/1up'
});
```